# How do I find & update or create an object in Rails in 1 call?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

So I tried this:

```
stock = Stock.find_or_create_by(ticker: ticker, jse_link: link, name: name, price: price)
```

It turns out that if ActiveRecord can't find a `Stock` object that matches all 4 attributes, it creates a new one. So if it finds an object that matches 3 of the 4 attributes, it creates a duplicate attribute.

Is there a simple way, without having to use `if` statements to do all of this in 1 call?

i.e. What I want to do is this:

- Find a `Stock` object that matches `ticker: ticker`.
- If that `Stock` object exists, then I want to update `price: price`.
- If that `Stock` object does not exist, then I want to create a new object with those 4 attributes (`ticker: ticker, jse_link: link, name: name, price: price`).

Can I do the above without having to use conditional statements?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you need to write if or else since you have different parameter to create and update.

```
stack = Stock.exists?(ticker: ticker) ? Stock.where(ticker: ticker).update(price: price) : Stock.create!(ticker: ticker, jse_link: link, name: name, price: price)
```

Comment: This is what my initial intuition was telling me, but I am wondering if it can be done without the conditional?

Comment: @marcamillion you can use an upsert. built into rails 6 now.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `find_or_initialize_by` and `tap`

```
Stock.find_or_initialize_by(ticker: ticker).tap do |stack|
  stack.price = price
  if stack.new_record?
    stack.jse_link = link
    stack.name = name
  end
  stack.save
end
```

Answer (score -1):

what you can do in concatenating queries:

```
stock = Stock.where(ticker: ticker).update(price: price).first_or_create(ticker: ticker, jse_link: link, name: name, price: price)
```

Comment: You mean `find_or_create_by()`, I assume?

Comment: Also this doesn't quite work because `first_or_create` and `find_or_create_by` are actually methods on an AR object, not a Ruby array.

Comment: @Usar I just tested it with a `ticker` I know is not there, and it still gives me the same error: `NoMethodError: undefined method 'first_or_create' for []:Array`

Comment: above query doesnt work if there is no stock object.

Comment: Also... if there is more than one match it will update the price for all with that ticker. Imagine separate exchanges with the same tickers for instance.